# How to update qty if the item is already exitst - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with Codeigniter cart
my problem is how to update the quantity of items if the item is already exist in the cart.

My model

```
function addToCart(){
    $data = array(
           'id'      => $this->input->post('product_id'),
           'qty'     => $this->input->post('qty'),
           'price'   => $this->input->post('price'),
           'name'    => $this->input->post('product_name'),
        );
                    $this->cart->insert($data);
                    redirect(base_url().'shopping-cart-view');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
function addToCart(){
    $data = array(
           'id'      => $this->input->post('product_id'),
           'qty'     => $this->input->post('qty'),
           'price'   => $this->input->post('price'),
           'name'    => $this->input->post('product_name'),
        );

    /* modification starts */

    $db_query = $this->db->get_where('cart', $data) ;
    $rows = $query->num_rows();

    if($rows > 0){
        // update the record
    }else{
        //insert record..
    }

    // modification ends

   redirect(base_url().'shopping-cart-view');
}
```